# Creating a whole new world with shapefile format of different layers in one file

Tags: d3.js, geojson, shapefile, qgis, topojson

I want to create a new world map and using **D3.js** with **topojson** and if possible **QGIS**. So at the end I need one **shapefile** that contains countrys, rivers, and so on. After creating all these layers I want that file converted by **mapshaper** so that the outcome is a **topojson**. So far so good.

I tried it with a simple polygon, so it was just one layer. I created the shapefile and than converted it to topojson. Now I wanted to use that file with d3:

```
{"type":"Topology","transform":{"scale":[0.8423423423423423,0.808252427184466],"translate":[1491.6423611111095,-3184.7916666666715]},"objects":{"country":{"type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":[{"type":"LineString","arcs":[0]}]}},"arcs":[[[437,17],[-7,87],[69,64],[23,74],[-31,80],[-14,54],[19,69],[-9,18],[-45,-35],[-53,-32],[-33,-12],[-26,-38],[-26,-27],[-29,-15],[-54,-12],[-29,22],[-40,27],[-31,10],[-36,35],[-2,30],[-17,57],[-14,19],[-19,28],[-31,62],[-2,47],[7,39],[17,40],[28,57],[119,37],[180,22],[247,-2],[105,-109],[78,-122],[52,-96],[55,-176],[-12,-109],[-47,-69],[-60,-77],[-104,-57],[-181,-7],[-49,30]]]}
```

This is just one polygon, that's right. This is my d3 code:

```
var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var path = d3.geo.path();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json("file.json", function(error, topology) {

  console.clear();

  var featureCollection = topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.country);
  var bounds = d3.geo.bounds(featureCollection);

  var centerX = d3.sum(bounds, function(d) {return d[0];}) / 2,
      centerY = d3.sum(bounds, function(d) {return d[1];}) / 2;

  var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .scale(3000)
    .center([centerX, centerY]);

  path.projection(projection);

  svg.selectAll("path")
      .data(featureCollection.features)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path);
});
```

But I always get "TypeError: t is undefined". But if I use a json file from someone else it's working. So how can I get this small example running? Is my QGIS bugging or maybe am I using it wrong? Thanks.

Or even do you know a better workaround for this?

Comment: Could it be that I didn't close the polygon? And taking any from the web is working well, so there must be something wrong with my own generated =/

Comment: Alright seemed like a bug, not it's working. I think I need some training with that GIS tool, that's all. But if anyone has an idea how else to do that task, let me know =)

Comment: Tried to replicate your problem [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/3USJBfNKnYZOcIEfGB3f?p=preview).  I don't get any errors, don't get a map either, not sure what's going on...

Comment: But must be a Plunker issue, same code is working on my PC =)

Comment: I tried Mark's code (without Plunker). Same result. No errors, no map.

Comment: Maybe play around with scale and center, or jsut remove them. That could fix the showing issue I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove

```
.scale(3000)
.center([centerX, centerY])
```

and it should work. Or edit it  to correct values.